# Underbraced text under sum is in different size from other

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

Text in underbrace under sum is bigger than other.

```
\sum_{{\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}=\{\underbrace{a,b,c,d}_{4\ terms}},e,f\}}
```

[image]

How can I solve this neatly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related: [consistent math font size in a formula](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150624/)

Answer (score 7):

You could add the math-mode directive `\scriptstyle` to the first argument of `\underbrace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % provides "\underbrace" and "\text" macros
\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{{\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}=\{\underbrace{\scriptstyle a,b,c,d}_{\text{4 terms}}},e,f\}}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, prompted by a comment by @Werner:

A second issue (besides the one raised in your posting, about getting the font size right for the first argument of `\underbrace`) arises if the width of the material in the second argument of the `\underbrace` macro is greater than that of the first argument. In such cases, you can encase the second argument in a `\mathclap` directive. (`\mathclap` is a macro provided by the `mathtools` package.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}      % provides "\mathclap" macro,
                            %    loads amsmath package
\setlength\textwidth{2.5in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
without \verb|\mathclap|:
\[
\sum_{\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}=\{\underbrace{\scriptstyle a,b,c,d}_{\text{Lots and lots of terms}},e,f\}}
\]

\medskip
with \verb|\mathclap|:
\[
\sum_{\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}=\{\underbrace{\scriptstyle a,b,c,d}_{\mathclap{\text{Lots and lots of terms}}},e,f\}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If `4 terms` is wider than `a,b,c,d`, you may want to consider using `\mathclap{..}` from [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).

Comment: @Werner - I've provided an addendum to illustrate how `\mathclap` can fix the problem that arises if the width of the second argument of `\underbrace` exceeds that of the first argument.